# Mysql not starting -> [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--query_cache_size-128M'

Tags: mysql

I have a big problem.

i try to start mysql in ubuntu, butI have this error:

```
130323  0:13:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0G
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130323  0:13:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130323  0:13:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130323  0:13:56 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1195255849922
130323  0:13:56 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--query_cache_size-128M'
130323  0:13:56 [ERROR] Aborting

130323  0:13:56  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130323  0:13:57  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1195255849922
130323  0:13:57 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This has no sense, because I dont use that in the my.cnf:

```
    #
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
#datadir                = /var/lib/mysql
datadir       = /home/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

#innodb_force_recovery = 3
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 500M
max_allowed_packet      = 128M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

default-storage-engine = INNODB

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 75
sort_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
table_cache            = 128K
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log-error=/var/log/mysql.err
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 50M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 32M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_table_locks = 0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Fix the typo. Then it should work.

Comment: the typo is the minus sign where equals should be: query_cache_size-128M -> query_cache_size=128M

Answer (score 10):

Check your my.cnf file for the options listed in the error logs and comment them out. Start mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Check your /etc/init.d/mysql if it's trying to start MySQL with this option.

Comment: ty, in /etc/mysql/conf/ there was a file with that opcion...I didnt make it...

Comment: What's the name of the file and what's the content?
It should be working if you fix it to `--query_cache_size=128M` (although you probably don't need this option at all, as it's overriding the `query_cache_size        = 16M` from your my.cnf).

Comment: Question is: "Any ideas? :("

I could also add an "If it is, remove the option" to my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this, apparently there is a file in my machine under /usr/ named my.cnf that has:

```
nnodb_force_recovery = 6
```

commented out and mysql starts fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error like **[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option  '--something'**
Only search for **something** in the my.cnf or my.ini file, and **carefully look at the content of something**.
Here **query_cache_size-128M** is wrong should be **query_cache_size=128M**, but other times it is caused by a line break in the wrong place and you get --0 or --n. In these cases search for a line with a single 0 or n on it, and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was a mistake on the configuration on the mariadb system configuration file.
There was some lines with mistakes.
by example

```
    mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.32 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-23 09:13:03 -03; 33s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 1638 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1639 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1641 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_>
    Process: 1688 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 1688 (code=exited, status=2)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
```

The Drop-In option are showing a file with errors in /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.cnf

There was a change on the startup of the service, and didn't start for that.
I modified this file, erasing his content and ejectute

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload

and then

> sudo systemctl start mariadb

And all works fine.
So, check modifications on systems initio

Answer (score 0):

We encounter nearly the same problem after a reboot of the ubuntu machine:

```
usr@ubuntu01:/etc/systemd/system$ systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.34 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-09-27 11:01:56 CEST; 22min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 3423 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3432 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3434 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-en>
    Process: 3499 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 3499 (code=exited, status=2)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

In `/var/lib/mysql/master2.err` we found following content:

        2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be change>
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait .>
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.34 started; log sequence number 1255185950; transaction id 1531069
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--Log-bin'
    2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Actual problem hided behind: `2022-09-27 11:34:10 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.`

After a long search session we changed 'Log-bin' into 'log-bin' inside '/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4Lb.png)

Comment: A) Do you mean you changed 'Log-bin' into 'log-bin=1' ?  
B) Is your system running now?

Comment: Hey initially there was only a 'Log-bin' in then mentioned mariadb.cnf file. I changed it simply to 'log-bin' , without adding a '=1'.  And yes my System is running now :)

Comment: Apparently upper / lower case does matter for this situation.  Glad you are running.

Answer (score -1):

Comment the parameters in my.cnf which gives error and then restart mysqld.

(For error check mysqld log file)